# How to match an input value with JSON data

Tags: html, json

Unable to match value of an input field with JSON data and then if matches display data. input value needs to match email field.

```
 <input type="text" name="useremail" class="center" placeholder="Email" id="useremail">
```

```
   $.getJSON(url,function(result){
     console.log(result);
     $.each(result, function(i, field){
       var id=field.id;
       var email=field.email;
       var message=field.message;

       if(field.email === "useremail"){
         $("#listview").append("<p>"+ id +"</p><p>"+ email + " </p><p>"+ message +"</p>");
       }
     });
   });
```

I have tried calling ID of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you need to change your if statement to:

```
if(field.email === document.getElementById("useremail").value){
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I had originally tried document.getElementById("useremail").html..... .Value is where I was going wrong

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to declare global variable for email id.
2. On page load you will get the json data. Set json email id to global variable.
3. Onchange get email id `email = (#id).val();` & match with global variable.

   if(global_var === email)
   {
       //code
   }